# Google Maps API: Change Opacity of Base Map without Changing Overlay's Opacity

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to change the opacity of the base Maps, without changing the opacity of any Overlays on top of the map?

I am setting up a map with an ImageMapType Overlay, and I'd like to have a separate opacity slider for both the base layer and the ImageMapType Overlay. ImageMapType has a `setOpacity(opacity:number)` method, but I can't find anything similar for the Map layer.

Answer (score 0):

Though undocumented and a little hacky, it looks like the DIV that holds all the base tiles comes right after the `google.maps.MapPanes.floatPane`

So you just need to call the following on an object that inherits OverlayView:
`overlayViewObject.getPanes().floatPane.nextSibling.style.opacity = 0.5;`